# How can I show that an entire function where the sum of real and imaginary part are less or equal to the absolute of the function is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, entire-functions

Suppose there is an entire function f with

$\Re(f(nz))+\Im(f(nz))\leq|f(z)|,\qquad \qquad \forall z\in\partial\mathbb{D}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N} $,

How could I show that $f$ is constant?

Comment: I guess you want to show that this inequality leads to $f$ bounded.  Then you'll apply Liouville's theorem (If $f$ is entire and bounded, then $f$ is constant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Letting $M=max|f(z)|, z\in\partial\mathbb{D}$ we get $\Re f(w) + \Im f(w) \le M, |w| = n, n \ge 1$. Since $\Re f + \Im f$ is real harmonic, applying the maximum principle on the domains $n \le |w| \le n+1$ leads to $\Re f(w) + Im f(w) \le M, |w| \ge 1$ which means that the image $f(\mathbb C)$ is disjoint of the set $|w| >2M, \Re w >0, \Im w >0$ and that is impossible for non-constant $f$ as $\infty$ cannot be an essential singularity, hence $f$ is polynomial, but the fundamental theorem of algebra implies $f$ constant then

Answer (score 0):

Can't we just use $|f(nz)| \leq |f(z)|$ for each $n, z,$
and the Maximum Modulus Principle to say $f$ is bounded by $\max_{z \in \partial D} |f(z)| = M < \infty?$

If $\forall w \in \mathbb{C}$ we find a larger radius $n > |w|,$ MMP bounds $|f(w)| \leq |f(nz)| \leq M.$ Such $f$ should be a constant by Liouville.